# Add the contents of a DataGridView to an existing XML file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

So I finally was able to create a XML and change it as I want but now I needed to add the contents of a `DataGridView` to it. I thought that's quite easy as I saw the options to place it into a `DataSet` and use `XmlWrite`, but that was a mistake of me. Note that I'm still trying to learn C# so probably I make a silly mistake here. It is still not working maybe someone is willing to point me out what I am doing wrong?

I actually have two issues with this:

1. It `ForEach` loop doesn't get the existing column names
2. It doesn't add the table and its contents to the XML file

   private void CreateClientFile()
   {
   string filename;
   filename = Company + "_" + SiteName + ".xml";

   ```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("CompanyProfile");
        doc.AppendChild(root);
        //Save document on Harddisk 
        doc.Save(@"C:\Users\NLRAGIL\Documents\10 - VibroManager\" + filename);
        //Need to save first and than load again????

        //Load document into program
        doc.Load(@"C:\Users\NLRAGIL\Documents\10 - VibroManager\" + filename);
        XmlNode main = doc.SelectSingleNode("CompanyProfile");

        //Create Company name element
        XmlElement companyname = doc.CreateElement("CompanyName");
        companyname.InnerText = CompanyName;
        main.AppendChild(companyname);

        //Create sitename element
        XmlElement sitename = doc.CreateElement("Sitename");
        sitename.InnerText = SiteName;
        main.AppendChild(sitename);

        //Create IMO element
        XmlElement imo = doc.CreateElement("IMO");
        imo.InnerText = IMO;
        main.AppendChild(imo);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("column" + i.ToString());
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                dr["column" + j.ToString()] = row.Cells[j].Value ;
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        //Create DataSet and add the datatable
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);          

        //Give the file name for where to write to.
        ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Users\NLRAGIL\Documents\10 - VibroManager\" + filename);

        //Show example for debugging
        doc.Save(@"C:\Users\NLRAGIL\Documents\10 - VibroManager\" + filename);
        System.Console.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);

    }
   ```

EXTRA CLARIFICATION:
The form I have looks as below:
[image: Client Profile]

The `Textbox` in the `groupbox` "Client Information" I'm able to save in a XML file. By altering the value of the numeric control I can express how much machine the particular client has. And the `DataGridView` gets more or less rows. But the information from the `DataGridView` I'm unable to append to the created XML file.

So the information from "Machine Name", "Serial No" etc I can't add to the XML file.

This is what I wanted to do, so later on in the program I can add certain measurements of each machine to it and store also in the same file.

But whatever I do my XML file looks like this:
[image]

I hope I explained it better now sorry for the confusion

Comment: A DataGridView isn't a data container, it's a UI control used to display data. What you need to serialize is that data, not the UI control. Where does the data come from?

Comment: As for why your file looks that way - you're overwriting the file with the DataTable contents with the contents of `doc` that haven't changed at all. You can't just append one XML doc after another anyway. There can only be a single root element in an XML document.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos The Machine Information and Company Information are entered manually. Just to create a profile. Next step would be to import data from a Vibration Recorder and import them to the program at the correct machine. This will be done in other forms. Again this is just to create a Company Profile with the Machines they have at their site.

The DataTable is not overwriting it cause when I press on the save button only the Company Information is stored and that part is before I do anything with the DataTable in the code.

Comment: I was thinking to follow previous advice and create a CompanyProfile Class and maybe also a Machine Information class and than i'm maybe able to store all that information in a XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is **Add the contents of a DataGridView to an existing XML file** and you say your first issue is that your `ForNext` loop is not giving you the column names and your second issue is that the code fails to serialize the record to an XML file on disk. These two goals can be simplified by using [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). This decouples your data from the view, making it easier to process. I would like to give you some insight if you wanted to try it out using the `CompanyProfile` in your code.

First, a `CompanyProfile` class declares the intended `public` properties:

```
public class CompanyProfile
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; } 
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string IMO { get; set; } = "Some Value";
}
```

Next, in your `MainForm` class a `BindingList<CompanyProfile>` is declared and attached to the `DataGridView` like this:

```
BindingList<CompanyProfile> DataSource = new BindingList<CompanyProfile>();
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    if(!DesignMode)
    {
        // Attach the data source to the view. Now changes to source records refresh in the view.
        dataGridView1.DataSource = this.DataSource;
        // Adding one or more records will generate the columns.
        DataSource.Add(new CompanyProfile { CompanyName = "Linear Technology", SiteName = "Colorado Design Center"});
        DataSource.Add(new CompanyProfile { CompanyName = "Analog Devices", SiteName = "1-1-2"});

        // Use string indexer to get a column
        dataGridView1.Columns[nameof(CompanyProfile.CompanyName)].AutoSizeMode = dataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.Columns[nameof(CompanyProfile.SiteName)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }
}
```

The resulting `DataGridView` now looks like this:

[image: Data grid view with two records]

This method makes a single file from a `CompanyProfile` record using `XmlSerializer` (but this is just one approach - and you could also serialize the entire list at one time if you choose).

```
private void CreateClientFile(CompanyProfile companyProfile, string fileName)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(CompanyProfile));
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        x.Serialize(writer, companyProfile);
    }
    // Open the file to view the result
    Process.Start("notepad.exe", fileName);
}
```

Now, iterate a `ForNext` loop on the `DataSource` not the `DataGridView`. You no longer need to worry about columns because you have the bound properties instead.

```
private void btnSerialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var appData = Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
            "datagridview_to_xml");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(appData);

    // Iterate the datasource list, not the DataGridView.
    foreach (CompanyProfile companyProfile in DataSource)
    {
        CreateClientFile(
            companyProfile,
            fileName: Path.Combine(appData,
            $"{companyProfile.CompanyName}_{companyProfile.SiteName}.xml")
        );
    }
}
```

Clicking the [Serialize] button reveals the two files.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your well explained answer. But I think I haven't explained what I want good enough. Nevertheless I learned some things form your answer so it wasn't a waist of your time.

So I will try to show you with some screenshots what I intend to do. Above in the original question.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful feedback and for adding the screenshot of your form. I hope you'll keep **Data Binding** in mind as a strategy because the general advice of making a **Model** that corresponds to your **View** still holds (even when the View is more complex than a simple list of records). You have the tools of Xml, Json, and SQLite to serialize and configure it. _And_ I notice you have some comments from one of the most expert people I know in that regard so you should be in good hands.

Comment: Heheheh thanks Ill hope I will make it work although im a bit affraid. I take to big task on my board. 
I managed first to make a class of the Client Profile and the program works as before so that means that the class is ok. Next step would be to fix a class for those machine data that comes from the datagridview. And I need to do some study about serialization and Databinding because these two things I've never worked with before and it als has been a while I worked with C# 

So lots of work to do for me

Comment: One other question I would like to ask is that when I try to make your example would I make the data binding. I do not know where to start. 

I have this 'frmClientProfile'  yes but the 'prtected override void'  I do not have. Should I make this by myself?

I'm sorry if this is a real silly question but this is the only way to learn IMHO

Comment: Sometime I got confused where to place certain code. I have
Private void frmClientProfile()
{ InitializeComponent()
}

As well

private void frmClientProfile_Load()

So these are two different functions/methods for the same form but abviously do different things. The load is only called when the form is loaded. Now I try to understand what you mentioned about the Protected Override, this is a completely different function seems to me but how is it called?

I really would like to learn more about it but MSDN is not always enough info for me

Comment: Thank you for the question. First for your previous comment: my first program was on punch cards. The year was 1975. I still get afraid. It's ok. To make `OnHandleCreated`, try typing `override` in your `Form` class. After that, enter a Space character to see the available overrides for `Form`. Visual Studio will generate the method for you. To gain a better understanding of what is happening "under the hood" read about [Polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/polymorphism).

Comment: Yes I see there are many option. I think I get the point this is a kind of action that takes place  and at your solution it starts running when 'OnHandeCreated'. Like I said I have something to study. I have some basic knowledge about programming but this kind of stuff seems to go more to intermediate :) 

If anybody who's following this thread has a good recommendation for a online training course about previous mentioned topics feel free to mention. Than I don't need to come all the time ith these questions :)

Comment: Regarding the punchcards I have colleages who started with this as well but these people understand programming the best. They have seen practically the whole evolution of software during their professional career.

Im from 1981 and got listing from my grandfather in GWBasic when I was about 10 years old. But during my professional career as electrical engineer specialized in electrical machines I never had the chance to become really profound in programming .... but it is so cool to do

Comment: As much as I'm enjoying this, sadly we must limit the "chit chat" to keep non-essential comments (a.k.a. "noise") at a minimum on the site :) so **keep asking questions** and most of all just keep coding I wish you the very best.

Comment: Ok no "chit chat" I've read the info about this forum this morning I respect that.

I wrote your code and works and I've learned a lot. But where in the code is stated that each row becomes a single file. I see you made a comment about this. But I don't understand that part